# Three problems with Java cipher and socket stream

Tags: java, sockets, inputstream, encryption

My three problems are as follows:

- I can't figure out how to pad the bytes and have it work without the error: `javax.crypto.BadPaddingException: Given final block not properly padded`
- If I switch it to NoPadding, I have to use a string thats a multiple of 8
- And lastly and most importantly, I can't get the Server to decrypt it correctly. I prove in the *CipherClient.java* that the decryption works before it gets sent over the socket.

Using the asHex, I can prove the CipherServer.java gets the same bytes, but when decrypting the message, it doesn't decrypt correctly.

Am I missing something? I don't understand how the Client can decrypt it correctly but once passed through the stream, the Server cannot.

I've been looking around the Internet all day at examples and I can't figure it out.
And before someone says something, I know DES isn't wise to use, however, this is just for a project, where DES is the requirement.

**CIPHERCLIENT.java**

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;
import java.security.*;

import javax.crypto.*;

public class CipherClient
{public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception 
{
    try {
        //Starts socket
        String host = "localhost";
        int port = 8001;
        Socket s = new Socket(host, port);

        //Generate a DES key.
        KeyGenerator keygen = KeyGenerator.getInstance("DES");
        keygen.init(56, new SecureRandom());
        SecretKey key = keygen.generateKey();           

        //Store the key in a file
        ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream("KeyFile.xx"));
        oos.writeObject(key);
        oos.close();

        //Start Cipher Instance and cipher the message
        //Cipher c = Cipher.getInstance("DES/ECB/PKCS5Padding");            
        Cipher c = Cipher.getInstance("DES/ECB/NoPadding");
        c.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE,key);

        //Get string and encrypted version
        //String message = "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.";
        String message = "12345678";
        byte[] encryptedMsg = c.doFinal(message.getBytes("UTF-8"));

        System.out.println("Client - Message: " + message);
        System.out.println("Client - Encrypted: " + CipherServer.asHex(encryptedMsg));


        //TEST DECRYPT W/ KEY FILE W/O SERVER (WORKS!)
        //-------------------------------

        //Read key from file test
            ObjectInputStream file = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream("KeyFile.xx"));
            SecretKey key2 = (SecretKey) file.readObject();
            System.out.println("Key Used: " + file.toString());
            file.close();

        //Decrypt Test
            c.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE,key2);
            byte[] plainText = c.doFinal(encryptedMsg);
            System.out.println("Decrypted Message: " + new String(plainText));


        //Open stream to cipher server
        DataOutputStream os = new DataOutputStream(s.getOutputStream());
        os.writeInt(encryptedMsg.length);
        os.write(encryptedMsg);

        os.flush();
        os.close();

        //Close socket
        s.close();

    }catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
 }
```

**CIPHERSERVER.java**

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;

import javax.crypto.*;


public class CipherServer
{
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception 
{
    //Start socket server
    int port = 8001;
    ServerSocket s = new ServerSocket();
    s.setReuseAddress(true);
    s.bind(new InetSocketAddress(port));
    Socket client = s.accept();

    CipherServer server = new CipherServer();
    server.decryptMessage(client.getInputStream());

    s.close();
}


public void decryptMessage(InputStream inStream) throws IOException, NoSuchAlgorithmException
{
    try {

        //Create the Data input stream from the socket
        DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(inStream);

        //Get the key
        ObjectInputStream file = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream("KeyFile.xx"));
        SecretKey key = (SecretKey) file.readObject();
        System.out.println("Key Used: " + file.toString());
        file.close();

        //Initiate the cipher
        //Cipher d = Cipher.getInstance("DES/ECB/PKCS5Padding");                        
        Cipher d = Cipher.getInstance("DES/ECB/NoPadding");
        d.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE,key);

        int len = in.readInt();
        byte[] encryptedMsg = new byte[len];
        in.readFully(encryptedMsg);         

        System.out.println("Server - Msg Length: " + len);
        System.out.println("Server - Encrypted: " + asHex(encryptedMsg));


        //String demsg = new String(d.doFinal(encryptedMsg), "UTF-8");
        //System.out.println("Decrypted Message: " + demsg);
        // -Print out the decrypt String to see if it matches the orignal message.
        byte[] plainText = d.doFinal(encryptedMsg);
        System.out.println("Decrypted Message: " + new String(plainText, "UTF-8"));


    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

//Function to make the bytes printable (hex format)
public static String asHex(byte buf[]) {
    StringBuilder strbuf = new StringBuilder(buf.length * 2);
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < buf.length; i++) {
        if (((int) buf[i] & 0xff) < 0x10) {
            strbuf.append("0");
        }
        strbuf.append(Long.toString((int) buf[i] & 0xff, 16));
    }
    return strbuf.toString();
}
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

You create your socket to the server before you create the key file, and the server properly read the key from last run.

Try moving the `Socket s = new Socket(host, port);` to after you have closed the key file.

The events is as follows:

```
    Client                 Server
    -----------------      ------------------
    Connect to server
                           Accept connection
                           Read key file
                           (block on receive)
    Generate Key
    Write Key File
    Send message
                           Receive message
    etc.
```

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the code I can only presume that the key is not correct. Maybe you are using a wrong folder or similar. `BadPaddingException` normally only occurs if the padding was incorrect, if the last block of the data has been corrupted or if you are using the wrong key. Maybe you could use a debugger or `SecretKey.getEncoded()` to check out if the keys together with your hexadecimal encoder.